# c# - Get current window title

Tags: c#, title

I'm writing a keylogger program. In my program, I want to write to log file current window title which is active. And if user changes to other windows, log file will be appended new title window. Here I have the code for getting windows title :

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd, string lpString, int cch);
    public static string ActiveApplTitle()
    {
        //This method is used to get active application's title using GetWindowText() method present in user32.dll
        IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        if (hwnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)) return "";
        string lpText = new string((char)0, 100);
        int intLength = GetWindowText(hwnd, lpText, lpText.Length);
        if ((intLength <= 0) || (intLength > lpText.Length)) return "unknown";
        return lpText.Trim();
    }
```

So, I don't know how to update window title when there's a change. Please give me an idea. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `I'm writing a keylogger` ---> good luck getting help here

Comment: Do you mean you want to be notified when the window's title changes so that you can call `GetWindowText` again?

Comment: Requests for writing malware is offtopic.

Comment: It is unclear what your question is, regardless the purpose of this code. Is your problem _"How to detect the foreground window changed"_?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Can you stick it in a loop on another thread. Have two variables: previousWindow and currentWindow. Keep comparing them, when they change - you update your log file.

Comment: I'm not sure which is more disturbing: that you consider this a reasonable solution, or that the OP accepted it as a reasonable solution. I sure hope I never run across software written by either one of you.

Comment: Well then do you care to elaborate what a proper solution would look like?

Comment: It's in the duplicate I posted.